# Read a text file in JAVA

Tags: java

Text file can be directly read using FileReader & BufferedReader classes.
In several technote, it is mentioned to get the text file as a input stream, then convert to Inputstreamreader and then BufferedReader.

Any reasons why we need to use InputStream approach

Comment: This is 2015. Don't use  `File` anymore. Use `Files.newBufferedReader()`.

Comment: or `Files.lines` or `Files.readAllLines` etc.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. So does it mean for any text data we can use reader class (With encoding mentioned in Bufferedreader). And use Inputstream only for Image and Video files ...?

Answer (score 7):

`FileReader` is convenience class for reading character files. The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are appropriate. To specify these values yourself, construct an InputStreamReader on a FileInputStream.

Comment: Thankd for the reply. In which scnerios we need to use Inputstream to get the text file and then pass it to InputstreamReader

Comment: @PanayappanSwaminathan Well ... The keyword here is _encoding_. If you need to specify an encoding, you simply can't use a `FileReader`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In which conditions we need to use encoding for text file.

Answer (score 0):

Complement to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33932875/1093528)...

There really isn't a need to use a `BufferedReader` if you don't need to, except that it has the very convenient `.readLine()` method. That's the first point.

Second, and more importantly:

- Use JSR 203. Don't use `File` anymore.
- Use try-with-resources.

Both of them appeared in Java 7. So, the new way to read a text file is as such:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("path/to/the/file");

try (
    final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path,
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
) {
    // use reader here
}
```

In Java 8, you also have a version of `Files.newBufferedReader()` which *does not* take a charset as an argument; this will read in UTF-8 by default. Also in Java 8, you have `Files.lines()`:

```
try (
    final Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(thePath);
) {
    // use the stream here
}
```

And yes, use try-with-resources for such a stream!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In which scnerios we need to use InputStream to get the file and bridge it to character set using Inputstreamreader

Comment: You don't need to; not with the new API. Well, you may need it if you want the default coding error action to be different than CodingErrorAction.REPLACE. For more details you may want to see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33921677/1093528).

Comment: So does it mean for any text data we can use reader class (With encoding mentioned in Bufferedreader). And use Inputstream only for Image and Video files ...?

Comment: If you know your input is text then yes, go for a `Reader`. Anything which is not text should make use of an `InputStream` instead. This is not just valid for files but for any byte stream you have to deal with (socket connections, etc).